sort groups by size and drop smaller groups
I would like to group some data, and:

sort groups by size
drop the groups with size less than 3.

In below sample, I would like to get the groups with order z, y since size of z is 4 and size of y is 3. but drop x since its size is 2.
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['x', 1],
    ['y', 5],
    ['z', 1],
    ['x', 43],
    ['y', 22],
    ['z', 2],
    ['y', 31],
    ['z', 3],
    ['z', 4],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'value'])
print(df)
dfg = df.groupby('name')
for name,df in dfg:
    print(name)
    print(df)

Current output:
  name  value
0    x      1
1    y      5
2    z      1
3    x     43
4    y     22
5    z      2
6    y     31
7    z      3
8    z      4
x
  name  value
0    x      1
3    x     43
y
  name  value
1    y      5
4    y     22
6    y     31
z
  name  value
2    z      1
5    z      2
7    z      3
8    z      4

expected:
  name  value
2    z      1
5    z      2
7    z      3
8    z      4
  name  value
1    y      5
4    y     22
6    y     31


I like @wjandrea's approach with transform, you could however get the same result without groupby by computing the value_counts (sorted by default in descending order) and reordering the filtered DataFrame with numpy.lexsort:
s = df['name'].value_counts()

out = (df[df['name'].map(s) >= 3]
       .iloc[lambda x: np.lexsort([x['name'], -x['name'].map(s)])]
       )

Output:
  name  value
2    z      1
5    z      2
7    z      3
8    z      4
1    y      5
4    y     22
6    y     31

If you want to split using groupby pass desired keys to get_group:
s = df['name'].value_counts()
dfg = df.groupby('name', sort=False)

for k in s.index[s>=3]:
    print(dfg.get_group(k))

Output:
  name  value
2    z      1
5    z      2
7    z      3
8    z      4
  name  value
1    y      5
4    y     22
6    y     31


lexsort can be expensive sometimes

@sammywemmy interesting, can you tell me more? I'd expect it to be at least as fast as sort_values on the same number of conditions

I have used it while trying to improve conditoonal_join and learned that sort_values just works better. Of course it is a limited test case, so take my comment with a positive nch of salt. I guess a better way to look at it would be np.isin does some sort as well (depending on data size) and numpy lexsort does an  argsort as well. A single sort would be better? Just my thoughts ... Nothing beats benchmarking

@sammywemmy I compared my current first approach with df.assign(n=df['name'].map(s)).query('n>=3').sort_values(['name', 'n'], ascending=False).drop(columns='n') and lexsort is 16.3 ms ± 375 µs per loop vs 17 ms ± 1.24 ms per loop for sort_values (and 21.7 ms ± 928 µs per loop for transform with my sort_values fix). Tested on df = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.random.randint(0, 50_000, 100_000)})

Note: If two groups have the same size, this will mix them up. See mozway's answer until I can figure out a solution
You can use groupby().transform('size') then use that to filter and sort. (Filtering first to avoid unnecessarily sorting data that that's going to be dropped.)
dfg = df.groupby('name', sort=False)  # No need to sort by key

df.reindex(
    dfg.transform('size')
    [lambda ser: ~ser.lt(3)]
    .sort_values(ascending=False)
    .index
)

  name  value
2    z      1
5    z      2
7    z      3
8    z      4
1    y      5
4    y     22
6    y     31


Nice one, I'd just use dfg = df.groupby('name', sort=False) to avoid unnecessarily sorting during the groupby. Note one possible issue of sorting the transformoutput, if two groups have the same size, the output might mix their rows (use np.lexsort in this case). Example using df = pd.DataFrame({'name': list('xyxyzyx')})

@mozway Apparently transformations don't do a sort, so that's nice :) Per the docs: "sort ... This argument has no effect ... in transformations"

it doesn't have an effect on the output of a transformation but sort=True still computes a sort during generation of the groups (which is is useless in this case). sort=False doesn't change the output but just makes the  computation a bit faster ;)

And a fix of your approach would be dfg = df.sort_values(by='name').groupby('name', sort=False) (that seems conterintuitive, but it's not doing the same!) combined with .sort_values(ascending=False, kind='stable') in the reindex

For this you could use the numpy library that allows you to create an array with the data you gave, then we continue using numpy to remove the unique groups and filter those that have at least 3 elements, in the end the only thing we have left to do is sort them and print the result.
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    ['x', 1],
    ['y', 5],
    ['z', 1],
    ['x', 43],
    ['y', 22],
    ['z', 2],
    ['y', 31],
    ['z', 3],
    ['z', 4],
])

unique_groups = np.unique(data[:, 0])
result = []

for group in unique_groups:
    group_data = data[data[:, 0] == group]
    if len(group_data) >= 3:
        result.append(group_data)

result.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
result = np.vstack(result) if result else np.array([])
print(result)


I suggest that you rewrite your code using numpy, so that the loops are done within C.

A possible solution:
g = df.groupby('name')
[x for _, x in g if len(x) >= 3]

Output:
[  name  value
 1    y      5
 4    y     22
 6    y     31,
   name  value
 2    z      1
 5    z      2
 7    z      3
 8    z      4]


In case you want the resulting groups sorted by size:
g = df.groupby('name')
sorted([x for _, x in g if len(x) >= 3], key=lambda y: -len(y))

Output:
[  name  value
 2    z      1
 5    z      2
 7    z      3
 8    z      4,
   name  value
 1    y      5
 4    y     22
 6    y     31]

